# Exec or Permission issue on IIS 8

Tags: php, permissions, exec, iis-8.5

I have a problem with my php webseite.
It is suppossed to run a batch file. The Batch starts a programm.
That programm is reading a file and creates a bmp and txt file.

This is my php code:

```
exec('cmd.exe /c "path\\to\\file.bat"');
```

The problem is when i run the php script i can see the programm in the task manager as "background processes" but no bmp or txt file is created. also the programm shuts itself down after creating the files.

i tried giving permission to the users but it seems i still make a mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem 3 months ago. The file is not created because the instance of cmd you’re running does not have administrative permission (i.e. run as administrator). The only solution I could find was to give the application pool for that app administrative permissions on cmd which ultimately resulted in me implementing a completely different approach since giving a website admin rights to the server is bound to end badly.

Hope this helps.